# Consulta con Group by me devuelve el resultado esperado en sentencia sql

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-10g

```
SELECT VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR,
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY')='05/2014' THEN 
  SUM(COMISION_VENTAS.VALOR_COMISION_BOLETA)
ELSE  0 
END "COMISION"

FROM VENDEDOR
JOIN BOLETA 
ON BOLETA.ID_VENDEDOR=VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR

JOIN COMISION_VENTAS
ON BOLETA.NRO_BOLETA=COMISION_VENTAS.NRO_BOLETA
group by VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR, TO_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY');
```

Esto  me muestra:

[image: esto me muestra por pantalla]

deberia quedarme :

```
|   | ID_VENDEDOR |COMISION|  
| 1 |   ___1111111|___33638|
| 2 |   ___2222222|___37464|
| 3 |   ___3333333|_______0|
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es aplicar el `SUM` al `CASE`, teniéndolos separados la información se desagrega. También agregué `O_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY')` al `SELECT` sino no puede apreciar correctamente el funcionamiento del `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR,
        TO_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY') 'Fecha',
        SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY')='05/2014' THEN COMISION_VENTAS.VALOR_COMISION_BOLETA
            ELSE  0
        END) "COMISION"
        FROM VENDEDOR
        JOIN BOLETA 
            ON BOLETA.ID_VENDEDOR=VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR
        JOIN COMISION_VENTAS
            ON BOLETA.NRO_BOLETA=COMISION_VENTAS.NRO_BOLETA
        GROUP BY 
            VENDEDOR.ID_VENDEDOR, TO_CHAR(BOLETA.FECHA_BOLETA,'MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

usa group tambien en el campo comision:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
mysql> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
       FROM sales
       GROUP BY year ASC WITH ROLLUP;
```